# How to slow down my transition. TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(myLayout) is too fast.

Tags: java, android, transition, slowdown

I have a method below that moves my imageView to the top left corner. It works perfectly, but it is going too fast. I would like to slow it down. I read up on it and saw that TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(myLayout) is what you should use to slow a transition. But it is still extremely fast.How can i slow this down??

```
 private void moveIcon() {
    View moveableIcon = findViewById(R.id.imageIcon);



    TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(myLayout);



    // change the position of the icon

    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams positionRule = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT ,

            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    positionRule.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP , RelativeLayout.TRUE);

    positionRule.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT , RelativeLayout.TRUE);

    moveableIcon.setLayoutParams(positionRule);


    // change the size of the button

    ViewGroup.LayoutParams sizeRules = moveableIcon.getLayoutParams();
    sizeRules.width = 70;
    sizeRules.height = 70;
    moveableIcon.setLayoutParams(sizeRules);


}
```